# Is it possible to change an object's (inherited) class after instantiated

Tags: c#, php, oop

I have a class, (for example, Vehicle) and I have a few other classes that inherit it (Car Inherits Vehicle; Truck Inherits Vehicle; etc)
I won't know what the inheriting class will be until be until I instantiate the object. Is it possible to change the class after it's inherited? For example, can I instantiate a Vehicle, do some logic to determine if it is a Car or a Truck, then apply the Car or Truck class to it afterwords?

Presently I have to pre-query to find out what type of vehicle it is, then use a switch/case to instantiate the appropriate class. I'd like to slim this down if possible and eliminate the pre-query; it seems like there should be a better way to do this.

Any advice or suggestions will be appreciated. I can build in either PHP or C#.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on why you don't know what the inheriting class will be until an object is instantiated? It feels like you have some kind of "VehicleBaseData" and also some logic (in the inheriting classes? or maybe the Vehicle class?) to decide, what inheriting class would be the best fit. So instead of directly trying to instantiate a `Vehicle`, why not create a factory with that decision logic, then instantiate a `VehicleBaseData` instead and give it to the factory to receive an instance of the correct inheriting class?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a reference to Base (Vehicle) class, but actual type should be known upon instantiation. You can refer that actual type with base class reference further, if needed.
example (c#):

```
Vehicle myFactory(int type)
{
    Vehicle v = null;
    switch(type)
    {
    case 0:
       v = new Car();
       break;
    case 1:
       v = new Truck();
       break;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: This looks very much like *then use a switch/case to instantiate the appropriate class* in the original question.